# How to check your XML documents does not contains any external resource

Tags: c#, xml, dtd

I would like to check the better approach to check for XML documents that contain external resource. 
I have received this error during veracode analysis.
Configure the XML parser to disable external entity resolution.

I can set the XMLResolve to null, but we depend on third party dlls too. So, I would like to validate the xml if it contains any external resource and reject the file immediately.

We do not use DTDs for our XML documents.
So here are the two options that I could think of. I guess both are almost the same. Just wanted to make sure if I'm missing anything.

```
//Check for DTD element in XML, if it contains, ignore this document. 
public bool IsValid(string xml)
{
   if (xml.Contains("<!DOCTYPE"))
   {
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

or

```
public bool IsValid(string xml)
{
    XmlReaderSettings xs = new XmlReaderSettings() {DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Prohibit};
    try
    {
            XmlReader.Create(xml, xs);
            return true;
    }
            catch (Exception ex)
    {
            return false;
    }
}
```

Also, this will only resolve DTDs, how can we check for other external resources like entities and schemas? What is the process to check for all the external entities? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would definitely go with the second option, since `<!DOCTYPE` could appear inside a `<![CDATA[` section.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I have edited my question. DtdProcessesing will prohibit only DTDs. While working on it it occured there might be other external resources, how we can avoid them?